# Azure using cached deployment script

Tags: php, azure, deployment, bitbucket

I have a PHP website that is automatically being deployed to Azure, this works well.

However, I would like to use a custom deployment script to automate moving certain files to Azure Storage/CDN on deploy. I've set up azure-cli using npm and created a deployment script using `azure site deploymentscript --php`. The deployment scripts were created and I've added my own script at the end of `deploy.cmd`.

My problem is that, the generated deployscript does not appear to be used. In the azure deploylog it says this:

**Generating deployment script**

`Using cached version of deployment script (command: 'azure -y --no-dot-deployment -r "D:\home\site\repository" -o "D:\home\site\deployments\tools" --basic --sitePath "D:\home\site\repository"').`

**Running deployment command...**
`Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
etc...`

That deploy.cmd is not the one it should be using- not the one I can change.

So, how do I get it to stop using a cached deploymentscript, or to use my custom deployment script?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. When I created my solution I didn't have a .deployment file. My solution consists of two projects. Inside one of the projects I have added a .deployment file, but I get the same info as you do for this project. Have you found any solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the .deployment in the root folder, and then the deployment.cmd inside the specific project. This way I got azure to do the non cache deployment. Just ensure that you update the path to the .cmd file inside the .deployment file.